# Creating a new subnet inside a classic azure vnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I am trying to create a new subnet inside an existing classic VNET on azure. Will creating a new subnet, take the VNET offline or will it cause downtimes to the apps that are present and working within other subnets inside the classic VNET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, when you are creating a new subnet in an existing classic VNet, it does not affect your VNet. It will not cause your apps not worikng.

**However, if you want migrate your apps from old subnet to new sunbnet, it will cause your apps downtime during the time.**